# How to transform tf::Vector3 with tf::TransformListener::transformVector?

Tags: transform-listener, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to convert a `tf::Vector3` with `tf::TransfomListener::transformVector(string("/base_link"), sourceV, targetV)`. What I get is the following:

*no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const tf::Vector3' to 'const Vector3Stamped& {aka const geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped_std::allocator<void >&}' *

Ok, so I figured I need a Stamped version of my vector. I tried this:

```
tf::Stamped<tf::Vector3> sv(sourceV, ros::Time(), string("/odom"));
```

and got this:

*no known conversion for argument 2 from 'tf::Stamped<tf::Vector3>' to 'const Vector3Stamped& {aka const geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped_std::allocator<void >&}'*

Then I realized that it is requesting `geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped`. How come the transformation listener from `tf` doesn't take `tf::Vector3`?

Ok, then I tried to get the right type:

```
    geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped gV;
    gV.vector = sourceV;
    gV.header.stamp = ros::Time();
    gV.header.frame_id = "/odom";
```

This resulted in:

*no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped_std::allocator<void >::*vector_type {aka geometry_msgs::Vector3*std::allocator<void >}' and 'const tf::Vector3')*

In the end my code looked like this:

```
    geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped gV, tV;
    gV.vector.x = sourceV.x();
    gV.vector.y = sourceV.y();
    gV.vector.z = sourceV.z();
    gV.header.stamp = ros::Time();
    gV.header.frame_id = "/odom";
    getTransformListener()->transformVector(string("/base_link"), gV, tV);
    targetV.setX(tV.vector.x);
    targetV.setY(tV.vector.y);
    targetV.setZ(tV.vector.z);
```

Even though I think this should be a one-liner without all that unnecessary object creation and assigment:

```
    getTransformListener()->transformVector(string("/base_link"), sourceV, targetV);
```

**Question:**

Is the one-liner somehow possible? Is there another easy way to do this that I am missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199376/how-to-transform-tf::vector3-with-tf::transformlistener::transformvector?/) by [Sheridan Vespo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21097/sheridan-vespo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you call the tf API the datatypes need to match, source and target. (tf2 supports implicit conversion but not tf.) Make sure that they both match and are stamped.

The assignment does not work between a tf datatype and geometry_msgs datatypes. You need to use the conversion functions: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/c++/transform__datatypes_8h.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RohitM](https://answers.ros.org/users/26985/rohitm/) on 2017-03-31**:
Are there python equivalents of these functions available?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The API says this should work: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transformer.html#aaad5b53acb0e2771e98beb6ac2b3fe56

I suspect your output/target vector just has the wrong type. It also has to be a stamped type.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1